# Probability of n points from a square area being all on their convex hull

Tags: random, convex-hulls

If we uniformly randomly generate n points in the unit square, what is the probability of all of them laying on their convex hull, i.e., they form a convex n-gon? I've been searching the internet and articles about the topic of CH, but all I've been able to find out is the expected amount of points in CH, probability of the CH being a triangle etc.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: This question has been initialy asked by Sylvester : see https://www.jstor.org/stable/2652854?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents Unfortunately, one hasn't access to the whole document.

Comment: I'm not sure whether we mean the same article now, but following your link, I've arrived at a free 16 page article about proving some random fact about the CH and random points. The intro though shows a beautiful formula that solves the exact problem that I have, except that it does so for a triangle, not a square. It was written by a Hungarian mathematician, was that the one you meant?

Comment: Yes it is the same "Sylvester's problem : the probability that n points are in convex position" but I have no access, whereas you are maybe with an URL that allows you to request Jstor articles... Sorry that it's for a triangle

Comment: Dont be sorry, I thank you! At least I have something, before, I had nothing